# VBA (Office 2010) Custom Class Method Throws "Object doesn't support this property or method" error

Tags: ms-access, vba

I've created a custom class called BitArray.  One of BitArray's methods, Append, takes a BitArray as an argument.  Here is the declaration for the Append method:

```
Public Function Append(ByVal newBits As BitArray)
```

(I've also tried passing newBits ByRef to no effect)

In my code, I have something like this:

```
Dim baBits1 As BitArray
Dim baBits2 As BitArray
Set baBits1 = New BitArray
Set baBits2 = New BitArray
baBits1.Append (baBits2)
```

The last line throws the 438 error.  Oddly enough, if I pull the code for Append out and execute it directly, it works.  So there is nothing inherently wrong with the logic or syntax within Append.  Does VBA not like class methods that can accept its own class as an argument?

Comment: The correct call is `baBits1.Append baBits2` or `Call baBits1.Append (baBits2)`. Do these work?

Answer (score 0):

VBA is fine with class methods that accept own class as an argument. 
ByVal and ByRef makes no difference when passing object variables - they will be always be passed ByRef regardless.

Try setting a breakpoint then using F8 to step through the code line by line to see where the error is.